# Pronunciation of "lorry", "worry" and "sorry"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have always pronounced *lorry* as "lur-ee" (as if to rhyme with *worry*), for as long as I can remember. Everyone else I know pronounces it as "lor-ee" (as if to rhyme with *sorry*).

Which one is correct, and why would the pronunciation of the vowel differ between *sorry* and *worry* when their spellings differ only in a consonant?

Comment: Since "sorry" is pronounced three different ways in the U.S., in the U.K., and in Canada. I've added the "british-english" tag.

Comment: Different UK regions pronounce things differently too. This could well be a Manchester thing (for example; I've never lived there).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I am, in fact, from Manchester, so you could be very much correct

Comment: @rickyduck: As a Southerner, I hear the Manchester *lorry/sorry* as quite close to both *marry/parry* ***and*** *worry/hurry*. The fact that you've got away with your [incorrect] pronunciation for so long suggests even your fellow Mancunians don't perceive/enunciate those differences as strongly as some other speakers.

Comment: @rickyduck I confess, I looked at your profile.

Comment: What way are you weirdos pronouncing the word *worry*? I'd rhyme all three of *lory*, *worry*, and *sorry*.

Comment: @TRiG _Worry_ certainly does not rhyme with _lorry_ and _sorry_ for me—it rhymes with _furry_.

Comment: The "o" in "lorry" is pronounced the same as that in "boring". The three words you present have three different "o" sounds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't do "correct", but I've never heard anybody pronounce "lorry" to rhyme with "worry".

I believe that the difference is because of the lip-rounding of the /w/. Many words starting with "w", "wh", "sw", "qu" or "squ" have different vowel sounds from similar words with a different consonant.

Eg

- *watch*, *what* vs *patch*, *thatch*, *pat*, *that*
- *war*, *warm*, *swarm* vs *far*, *farm*
- *worth*, *worm* vs *forth*, *form*

(There are exceptions to this rule).

Comment: Adequate answer to my question. Sort of like _wan_ should sound like _man_, but instead makes a _won_ sound (_wanted_)... except in other cases such as a widely used swearword with the same first three letters (can't think of any other examples). 

My argument for using _"lurry"_ has always been _worry_ is the same spelling yet different sound... I guess this eliminates that defense.

Comment: I'm not sure "lip-rounding of the /w/" makes much difference. Most people wouldn't confuse *hot* and *hut*, which seem to me to be the same vowels as *lorry/hurry*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For me, *hot, hut, lorry, hurry* have **four** different vowels.

Comment: @tchrist: That's probably the American in you, being affected by the "r" that many of us Brits barely enunciate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Hurry* is like *her* with an *ee* on the end.  *Lorry* is like *lore* with an *ee* on the end.  Nothing at all like the others.

Comment: @Jwpat7: that was supposed to read "I don't do 'correct'". Oops.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in my UK English, "hurry" has a different vowel from "her". And my point about lip-rounding is not about being able to distinguish sounds, but a hypothesis about why the sounds have (more or less systematically) changed.

Comment: @rickyduck: a following velar often seems to suppress this change: consider "quack", "whack", "wag" as well as your example,

Comment: @Colin: My apologies for not having paid sufficient attention first time around. Actually, even though I'm not really qualified to judge, your hypothesis sounds pretty convincing to me. So here's my long-overdue upvote! (plus I took the liberty of editing to make jwpat's comment obsolete! :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a case that "lurry" is the original pronunciation.

The Online Etymological Dictionary gives this origin: "a truck; a long, flat wagon," 1838, British railroad word, probably from verb *lurry* "to pull, tug"(1570s), of uncertain origin. Meaning "large motor vehicle for carrying goods" is first attested 1911."

According to Wikipedia, meanwhile, before the railway "lorry" is attested in 1838  there was a horse-drawn "lorry", a low flat trailer for transporting other vehicles. Both of these were also referred to as "lurries" in the early period and this pronunciation seems to have been preserved in English dialect.

"Lurry" is certainly used here in Stockport by older and more conservative locals, but I first heard "lurry" from my grandmother (b. 1907 Cockfield, County Durham) referring to the horse drawn vehicle used to take her on a Sunday school picnic as a girl. She distinguished between that and the motorised "lorry".

I must point out though that the "u" of "lurry" as pronounced in the Teedale dialect of that generation is not the same as in Greater Manchester now; it is not as rounded as Yorks-Lancs /ʊ/ but not as open as the Southern English /ʌ/ I'd guess, but I am not a phonetician. I do know, however, that at the time the horse-drawn lorry was being transformed into the steam drawn lorry the English "u" was in a state of flux. My guess is that the spelling of "lorry" first recorded as a railway term in 1838  was originally an approximation to a dialectal pronunciation. The pronunciation "as spelled" has since become the norm.

Comment: Brilliant and articulate answer. Thank you for this! And only a score of 21!

Answer (score 3):

I grew up in NW UK saying lurry (for lorry) but my more 'northern' boyfriend and his family insisted it was lorry so I changed my pronunciation.

Comment: Are you saying you rhymed *lorry* with *worry* and *hurry* instead of with *sorry* and *Tory*?

Comment: yes, lorry-worry-hurry as a child, now worry-hurry rhyme together as do lorry-sorry but Tory is different again with an 'ore' rather than 'o' or a 'u' sound. I can't think of a rhyme for Tory. . .

Comment: How about *Story*?

Comment: @CarlSmith still doesn't rhyme with lorry

Comment: @rickyduck, I doubt that CarlSmith rhymes with anything.

Comment: @jwpat7 Cardiff?

Comment: @jwpat7 Unless you start getting a bit blasphemous and describe the aging Emperor Palpatine as a _gnarled sith_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Manchester and have always pronounced it Lurry as have my family and a number of my local friends.
It’s always been the norm to me!
However the younger generation and now even my daughter have started pronouncing it lorry (which always sounds scouse to me) 
Both are probably right depending where you come from and how old you are.
As a middle aged Manc I will stick with Lurry

Answer (score 0):

Pronunciations practically always differ regionally. I don't say *lor-ee* and *sor-ee*. I say *lah-ree* and *sah-ree* with a really low in the throat ***o*** like the doctor makes you say when he says, "go awh". But it still rhymes with *sorry* and not *worry* for me.

Why do they not rhyme with *worry*? Well, English has lots of word pairs with identical vowels and different pronunciations. Like *bead/head*, *have/save*, *blow/wow*, *watch/hatch* to name only a few.

Etymology or word origins can be a big influence. *Sorry* evolved from Old English *sarig* and *worry* evolved out of *wyrgan*, so they didn't always have the same vowels.

Answer (score -3):

[Rhymezone](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?&typeofrhyme=perfect&loc=moreideas&Word=sorry)

They should rhyme due to the spelling, not because the sound that the words make differs slightly. They, almost rhyme

Comment: Nothing in the English language “should r[h]yme due to the spelling”. Spelling does not dictate how anything is pronounced in English, and rhymes are completely orthogonal to spellings.