# Why is the word watch pronounced differently from words like patch, latch, match, catch, and batch?

Tags: pronunciation

Why doesn't *watch* rhyme with *catch, batch, latch, patch,* and *match*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "chore" pronounced differently from the "chore" in "choreography"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24257/why-is-chore-pronounced-differently-from-the-chore-in-choreography)

Comment: @HotLicks: that is in no way a duplicate. If you don't like this class of question, just downvote it, but don't leave useless comments.

Comment: Funnily enough, there are dialects in Scotland that do pronounce watch the same way as those other words. :P

Comment: @sumelic - What are the first 3 words in the highest-voted answer of that link?

Comment: @HotLicks: Three-word answers are not acceptable here. Also, that would be wrong. These words originally had the same sound, but are now pronounced differently because of sound change. An actual duplicate is more like the following post: [The pronunciation of “was” has changed since the Seventeenth Century. When and why did it change"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174417/the-pronunciation-of-was-has-changed-since-the-seventeenth-century-when-and-w)

Comment: @sumelic - So, enter that as a dupe.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there are any other questions that cover the subject. You could spend some time looking around also, or you could just ignore the question. It's not helpful to anyone to leave irrelevant comments.

Comment: Here are other related questions (or questions with related answers): [Pronunciation of “lorry”, “worry” and “sorry”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88191), [Pronunciation and meaning: “wind” and “wound”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131165)

Comment: Is then any reason that they should be pronounced the same? Phonology and orthography are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the rounded lips of the preceding consonant "w".

Many (but not all) English words with an "a" following "w", "wh" or "qu" have a different vowel from similar words with a different consonant.

So

> what vs. that
>
> watch vs. catch
>
> squash, wash, vs. cash
>
> war, warm vs car, arm

The exceptions often have a velar (/k/, /g/, or /ŋ/) or /m/ following the "a":

> *wag, whack, quack, wangle, swam, wham* have the vowel of *tag, tack, tangle, tram*  not the vowel of *wad, what, quad, wan*.

But there are exceptions to this rule as well:

> *Quag* has the vowel of *quad* despite its velar; and *warm, swarm* have the vowel of *war*, not that of *harm*.

Comment: I think both pronunciations are used for *quag* and *quagmire.*

Comment: I am not sure this is convincing. Firstly because in my native Yorkshire, watch is often pronounced to rhyme with catch, and secondly because we have words like consider, botch, lost, pot, and mop that lack the rounded lips of a "w" but still have the initial vowel sound of watch.

Comment: @RoaringFish: for local pronunciations without rounding: I said that it didn't apply to all such words anyway: you're just saying that the list of exceptions is diffierent in different dialects. For the second list: I didn't say that _all_ instances of /ɒ/ were affected by a preceding /w/; just that many of those where you would expect /æ/ have a preceding /w/.

Comment: @ColinFine ~ I have no problem with the observation that a word-initial /w/ is often followed by a LOT vowel. My issue is purely with your first sentence that suggests the LOT vowel is *because of* the /w/ as though it is an ease of articulation situation. I see no reason to believe that a TRAP vowel following a word-initial /w/ is any harder to articulate than a LOT vowel. Similarly, a word-initial consonant of any form can be followed by either TRAP or LOT with equal ease.

Comment: @RoaringFish: fair comment: correlation does not imply causation. Nevertheless, the fact remains that a majority of English words where 'a' follows 'w' or 'qu' (and there is no following 'e' or equivalent) have a rounded vowel - the LOT vowel or the WAR vowel where there is an orthographic 'r' following - and few words with 'a' not preceded by 'w' or 'qu' have these vowels. Assuming this is not an arbitrary orthographic convention (which is possible, but I know of no reason why it should be) the obvious assumption is that the preceding rounding has modified the vowel sound.

Answer (score -1):

They are derived from different Old English words and some of the old pronunciation has lingered on. Batch from a word related to bacan which has to do with baking. Watch comes from waeccende meaning to stay awake.

That being said, words sometimes change pronunciation for no particular reason. On reading John Clifford's comment I should add that regionalism makes a difference as well. Different linguistic groups pronounce words differently. In New York, for instance, the words "Mary", "marry", and "merry" are pronounced quite differently but in most other English-speaking communities they sound the same.

Maybe I should have limited my answer to "just because".

Comment: No, it's not a lingering old pronunciation. Latch comes from *laeccan," with  the same "aecc" sequence as in the ancestor of "watch." It's a relatively new sound change that altered the vowel in "watch." In fact, I believe this change is not even universal to all modern dialects of English. This sound change is not unexplainable; it fairly regularly affected words with the sequence "wa," with some fairly regular classes of exceptions.